# WPF DataGrid pressing enter on first cell it is adding new row I want it to add new row on las cell pressing enter

Tags: wpf, datagrid

WPF Datagrid it is adding new row while pressing enter on first cell I want it to add new row once I press last cell of Datagrid.

Please check demo app is here:

[WPFDemo](https://github.com/jitendrajadav/WPFDEMO)

Thank you,
Jitendra Jadav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGrid` also adds a new row even when you don't even press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. If you don't want this behaviour, you would probably be better of setting the `CanUserAddRows` property to `false` and add the items yourself to the source collection. Something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGrid.CanUserAddRows = false;
        //add blank row
        var itemsSource = dataGrid.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<ItemModel>;
        if (itemsSource != null)
            itemsSource.Add(new ItemModel());

        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        dataGrid.PreviewKeyDown += DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown;
    }

    private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            if (Keyboard.FocusedElement is UIElement elementWithFocus)
            {
                if (dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1 == dataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex)
                {
                    var itemsSource = dataGrid.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<ItemModel>;
                    if (itemsSource != null)
                    {
                        var newItem = new ItemModel();
                        itemsSource.Add(newItem);

                        dataGrid.SelectedItem = newItem;
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> 
                        {
                            DataGridRow row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(newItem) as DataGridRow;
                            DataGridCell cell = Helper.GetCell(dataGrid, row, 0);
                            if (cell != null)
                                dataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(cell);
                        }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    elementWithFocus.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Helper.SelectRowByIndex(dataGrid, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much